# How to combine two independent estimates of location

Tags: signal, gsm, algorithm

For finding mobile location we know two methods:

- [Trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) of **signal strength** and
- [Timing Advance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_advance).

Now to improve accuracy we need to use both methods simultaneously. We are able to use both the methods independently but now able to use with each other to improve accuracy.

How can we do this?

Comment: @Andyaka Actually we have no way to find direction. We get signal strength.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, sorry my mistake. Can trilateration and TA method used simultaneously to get better accuracy.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick my comments are deleted (apart from this one)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you're really looking for is improved resolution, not accuracy.

The Timing Advance numbers give you good accuracy, but relatively poor resolution (on the order of 500 meters). RSSI numbers can potentially give you better resolution, but have much poorer overall accuracy. The latter depends on how well you can model the signal strength vs. distance curve, and how well this characteristic is matched with respect to the different base stations.

You could potentially use a Kalman filter to combine the results for improved resolution. Your filter would include state variables that model the errors in the individual RSSI measurements. However, this method would not help for measuring static position; the device would have to be moving in order to generate data that the filter can use.

Comment: +1. Though mobile is moving,but we want static location. Still I will go through Kalman filter as you suggested. May be I will get my solution there.